# java script как назначить option атрибут selected нажатием на button

Tags: javascript

Суть в том, что у меня есть select  с месяцами, где стоит дефолтный текущий месяц, и мне нужно его поменять на другой при нажатии на button добавления задачи.

То есть в select должен отобразиться месяц тот на который добавляю задачу. Как это сделать? Тем более value в option формируется динамически в зависимости от года.

То есть я как то должен выбрать option где value равно переменной в которой будет значение при котором option станет selected - логика мне понятна кажется а как написать не знаю=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменить `value` достаточно просто сделать `selectEl.value = 'value'`
Чтобы получить имя выбранного месяца я использовал `selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].text`, то есть обратился к массиву `options` и вытащил по индексу выбранного option(`selectedIndex`).

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.onclick = () => {
  select.value = 4
  
  const name = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text
  
  console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">
    Январь
  </option>
  <option value="2" selected>
    Февраль
  </option>
  <option value="3">
    Март
  </option>
  <option value="4">
    Апрель
  </option>
</select>

<button>Изменить месяц</button>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло.